# Reading a Variable that Exists in a Delegate Function

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a delegate that modifies a variable called `tagToIndex`, and I am trying to return the modified variable from the delegate. `tagToIndex` is defined earlier on in the class, but it does not contain the information I need.

My question is, is there any way to read the variable `tagToIndex` as it exists within the `willPressItemAt` function? As of right now, I have no way of reading the variable outside of the function.

Obviously I cannot use the `return` command on `willPressItemAt`, because that would require I feed in parameters which I cannot do. Additionally, I tried to use delegates but it didn't really solve the problem.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell, YSSegmentedControlDelegate {

var tagToIndex = [0:0,1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0,5:0]

let actionButton = YSSegmentedControl(
    frame: CGRect.zero,
    titles: [
        "Yes",
        "No"
    ])      
}    

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt index: Int) {
    tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index
    print(tagToIndex)

}

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, didPressItemAt index: Int) {

}
```

}
Above is the delegate function, where the version of `tagToIndex` I want exists. **I want to be able to access `tagToIndex` within the MyCell class**

Another possibility would be to simply modify tagToIndex outside of the function, but I would need `index`, which is a value that only exists within the function. When I perform `print(index)` within `viewDidLoad`, all it returns is `(function)`.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: You have to be more specific. `tagToIndex` seems to be an instance variable so why don't you have access to it?

Comment: `tagToIndex` is an instance variable. I've read about instance variables, but i'm not familiar enough with them to fully understand how they work or how to use them properly (I'm still pretty new to this). Does that mean I should be able to access tagToIndex as it exists in willPressItemAt? If so, is there a special way of doing it?

Comment: The problem is that you don't even tell us where you want to access that variable.

Comment: Alright, I edited the post. I want tagToIndex to be accessible within the MyCell class as of right now, and I will work from there.

Comment: It is alreasy accessible there. You are using it.