# How to access a variable within a Delegate Function?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a class `MyCell` that has a delegate and an instance variable `tagToIndex`. I want to print this variable after it is modified by the delegate. Currently my code looks like this:

```
 class MyCell: UITableViewCell, YSSegmentedControlDelegate {

 var tagToIndex: Dictionary<Int,Int>?

    func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt index: Int) {

  tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index

}


print(tagToIndex)
}
```

The problem is that instead of printing `tagToIndex` as it exists in the delegate function (`willPressItemAt`), `tagToIndex` is nil.

I have also tried using a callback to send the index back to the view controller. The code looks like this:

```
var switchTapIndex: ((Int)->Void)?

func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt index: Int) {


    switchTapIndex?(index)

}
```

Unfortunately the value still returns "nil" when I print it in a separate function. Maybe I am failing to fully understand how callbacks work, but I do not understand how what I am doing is any different than using a callback within a switch function like so:

```
var switchTapAction : ((Bool)->Void)?
func switched(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    print("Switched: \(sender.isOn)")

    // send the Switch state in a "call back" to the view controller
    switchTapAction?(sender.isOn)
}
```

Comment: If you want to print it after it has been modified by the delegate, why is the `print` statement outside the relevant method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a Variable that Exists in a Delegate Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679900/reading-a-variable-that-exists-in-a-delegate-function)

Comment: I not only have to print it, I have to actually use the variable at other points in the class.

Comment: You need to Stop posting the same question over and over and over. Stick with one question... respond to people's comments... if you're not getting the answer you want, then you need to think about what you are asking, and try to be clear about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to be an clearer. If you could tell me what parts you don't understand that would help me a lot. The question makes sense to me, but it may not make sense to other people.

Comment: @NicholasTiwari Please, stop posting what is basically the same question again and again. Instead of trying to clarify in the comments,  [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44702663/edit) your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @NicholasTiwari - I went back a few of your posts and found an image... your question should be "I want to use a Segmented Control as a Yes/No switch in multiple table rows... How do I track in my ViewController when the user taps the switch in the cell?" That *is* what you're really trying to learn, right?

Comment: @NicholasTiwari - if that *is* what you're trying to do, take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369289/swift-3-uiswitch-in-tableviewcell-loses-state-when-scrolling/44370083#44370083 ... it is using a UISwitch, but you should easily be able to modify it to handle the YSSegmentedControl  willPressItemAt or didPressItemAt function.

Comment: I took a look at it. The problem I am having is similar to what you are doing with the callback. In your example, the switch state is sent to the view controller via a callback. I want to do something similar in my own code with the index, however I have not been able to get this to work. The edited code is posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Here you might be getting `tagToIndex` as nil because you are not initializing that variable. Just try,

```
  func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt index: Int) {
    if tagToIndex == nil {
    tagToIndex = Dictionary()
    }
      tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index

    }


    print(tagToIndex)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line declares `tagToIndex` as a property of type `Dictionary<Int, Int>?`. In other words, it is an optional `Dictionary` mapping from `Int` to `Int`. Optional properties default to `nil`. Since you haven't initialized it, it's `nil`.

`var tagToIndex: Dictionary<Int,Int>?`

Make that property non-optional by removing the `?`, and initialize it:

`var tagToIndex: Dictionary<Int,Int> = [:]`